# How to get the indexOf an element in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to get the indexOf the element in an element array in JavaScript.

Here's the code:

```
function redrawchatbox(chatbox) {
//chatbox is a html element.
chatbox.remove();
variable = variable - 280;
redraw = document.getElementsByName("chatbox");
// this is the error - gives me redraw.indexOf is not a function.
closedchatbox = redraw.indexOf(chatbox);
for (i = redraw.length; i > 0; i--) {
    x = i - 1;
    redraw[x].style.right = (parseInt(redraw[x].style.right.replace("px", "")) - 280) + "px";
}}
```

I want to get the index of the chat box closed so I can redraw all the chatbox in the right positions.  When I use indexOf on the redraw array it throws me that error.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: have you tried printing to the console the var "redraw"? It's clearly not an array, most likely undefined or the actual tag. Print that to console and tell us what you get.

Comment: indexOf is a function used on get index of character occurence in a String as shown here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 2):

That's because `getElementsByName` returns a `HTMLCollection` which is an array-like object not an array. You should convert the collection into an array then use the `indexOf` method.

```
var chatboxArr = [].slice.call(closedchatbox);
var index = chatboxArr.indexOf(chatbox);
```

The `Array.prototype.slice` method can be used to create a shallow copy of an array. In the above snippet the `slice` method is `call`ed with the collection as it's `this` value and as result it returns an array that contains items of the `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: What exactly is this doing step by step?

Comment: how to put this to my code i cant understand the logic :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
closedchatbox = redraw.indexOf(chatbox);
```

with this:

```
closedchatbox = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(redraw, chatbox);
```

`getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, which is not an array but an "array-like object".  It does not have an `indexOf` method itself, but the `Array` method can be applied to it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because getElementsByName returns a NodeList object.